# Referenced Bean not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and am using Spring 3.2.5 RELEASE. I have a custom UserDetailsSevice called MongoUserDetailsService. This is my application-security.xml.

```
<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/secured/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/loginPage"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/secured/mypage" authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?auth=fail" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutPage" />        
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="mongoUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoUserDetailsService" class="com.srccodes.spring.security.MongoUserDetailsService">
</bean>
```

I receive a bean not found error in application-security.xml  where the authentication-provider is provided. I have checked the paths and they are correct.

I am adding my web.xml as well.

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring context files to be loaded -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/mongo-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- filter declaration for Spring Security -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

in application-security.xml file must import the dispatcher-servlet.xml the following code is showing the import sysntax:
1- if dispatcher-servlet.xml is buildPath:

```
<import resource="classpath:DIR/dispatcher-servlet.xml" />
```

2- if it is WEB-INF DIR

```
<import resource="DIR/dispatcher-servlet.xml" />
```

i hope to help you

Comment: Shows an error saying import  is not allowed in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined your `application-security.xml` as a root context (i.e, it's loaded via ... ContextLoaderListener) and your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` via `DispatcherServlet`, you'll have visibility/scoping issues. The DispatcherServlet context are children to root context, therefore beans defined in DispatcherServlet context ARE NOT visible to root context, but root context beans ARE visible to all children servlet contexts.

So move your `mongoUserDetailsService` to your application-security.xml

UPDATE:

You are loading your dispatcher-servlet.xml configurations twice, once explicitly at

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/mongo-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and again implicitly (by Spring convention) with the DispatcherServlet. You should checkout the [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) for better understanding of ApplicationContext and DispatcherServlet

1. You need to remove dispatcher-servlet.xml from contextConfigLocations
2. Your dispatcher-servlet.xml should only include Spring MVC related config. Unless it's your intention, the following component-scan is too inclusive, you should limit it to spring mvc related (e.g. controllers), move things like security, repositories to a root context.

> ```
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring" /> 
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.security" />
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.domain" />
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.repositories" />
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />
> ```

3. move your mongoUserDetailsService to the application-security.xml

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... pressing needs. How do I move the service to my application-security.xml? Please have a look at my web.xml  that I  have added.

Comment: 1. I removed dispatcher-servlet.xml. Then I moved security and repositories to applicationContext.xml. (new file). I am stuck at moving mongoUserDetailsService to the application-security.xml. I tried <bean id class> ... but pops up an error. This is the only part holding up. Can you provide an example?